# Laravel Sitemap ChildNodes

Tags: laravel, sitemap

I am trying to Create sitemap with Laravel,
I want to give an alternative url because it is multi-language, it is created nicely, but sitemap.xml
file unfortunately gives console error

```
caught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'childNodes')
    at i (viewer.js:1:1401)
    at Object.s [as checkIfJson] (viewer.js:1:2212)
    at XMLDocument.r (viewer.js:7:22942)
```

```
use Spatie\Sitemap\Sitemap;
use Spatie\Sitemap\Tags\Url;

Route::get('/sitemap', function () {
 $sitemap = Sitemap::create();
 $url = Url::create('/')
  ->setChangeFrequency('always')
  ->setLastModificationDate(Carbon::yesterday())
  ->setPriority('0.7');

 $url->addAlternate('/en', 'en');

 $sitemap->add($url);
 $sitemap->writeToFile(public_path('sitemap.xml'));

 return 'Sitemap Created Successfully';
});
```

What is the reason for the console error